# Is there a simple way to create a cross-shaped array in ConTeXt?

Tags: math-mode, matrices, context

According to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays, the following code creates an array that has a cross-shape, with four items centered in each quadrant.

```
\begin{array}{c|c}
    1 & 2 \\ 
    \hline
    3 & 4
\end{array}
```

The desired result is this, with the numbers centered vertically and horizontally within their quadrants.

```
1 | 2
-----
3 | 4
```

Since I'm placing text, not math, `\startcombination` seems to be the right code, but I don't see a way to add rules.

Is there a simple equivalent in ConTeXt? ConTeXt Garden mentions `\startarray`, but this command is reported as not found when I add it to my code. I can create this in MetaPost or with a table, but I wonder if there is a more proper way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of LaTeX's `tabular` in ConTeXt is `\start...\stoptabulate`.  I'm not sure whether that is the best solution in your situation.  Maybe you can clarify the question.

```
\starttext

\starttabulate[|c|c|][distance=none]
  \NC 1 \VL 2 \NC\NR
  \HL
  \NC 3 \VL 4 \NC\NR
\stoptabulate

\stoptext
```

[image]